# What is difference between ip_hdr and ipip_hdr?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel

In include/linux/ip.h,

```
23 static inline struct iphdr *ip_hdr(const struct sk_buff *skb)
24 {
25         return (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);
26 }
27 
28 static inline struct iphdr *inner_ip_hdr(const struct sk_buff *skb)
29 {
30         return (struct iphdr *)skb_inner_network_header(skb);
31 }
32 
33 static inline struct iphdr *ipip_hdr(const struct sk_buff *skb)
34 {
35         return (struct iphdr *)skb_transport_header(skb);
36 }
37 #endif  /* _LINUX_IP_H */
```

if I passed in sk_buff to ip_hdr and ipip_hdr

```
struct iphdr *ip_hdr ip_hdr_net = ip_hdr(skb);
struct iphdr *ip_hdr ip_hdr_trans = ipip_hdr(skb);
```

ip_hdr_net->saddr and ip_hdr_trans->saddr point to the same thing? I tried it on code. It doesn't. It seems that only ip_hdr_net->saddr point to source IP address.

So questions:

(1) what is differences between ip_hdr and ipip_hdr? Why we have them? No documentation whatever to figure it out.

(2) should I use ntohX function to convert ip_hdr member data when accessing them? eg, ip_hdr_net->saddr.

Answer (score 1):

ipip is ip over ip tunneling protocol.

Detail Info about the protocol is here:

http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.tunnel.ip-ip.html

You can browse the source code about its Linux implementation here:

[ip over ip tunnel code xref in kernel](http://www.srcmap.org/sd_share/4/83a63ed3/ip_over_ip_tunneling_in_Linux_kernel.html#RefId=7c8f5285%22777%22)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I got the exact same answer from kernel newbie mailing list.